# What is the best way to upload & access images in Yii2 advanced?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new to Yii2 & I have the following question: what is the best way to upload & access images in Yii2 using advanced template?
Let's say I have `common\models\User` model with `avatar` attribute and I want to upload & access this image from both environments: backend & frontend. So what is the best way to do this?
Important note: accessing this image in views I may not know from which environment the image was uploaded (by admin or custom user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Create a separate folder for static resources

You could serve all your static files in a cookie-less subdomain `static.mysite.com` that would point to a `/static` folder in the root of your project. Create aliases for that in your `common/config/main` file: `@static` and `@staticPath` for example, use that through the code.

When you are saving an image, either from the backend or frontend, you use the alias, for example

```
Image->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@staticPath/img/users/') . $user->avatar)
```

When you are displaying the images, use the alias.

```
Html::img(
  Yii::getAlias('@static/img/users/') . $user->avatar
)
```

You could go even further and create aliases that point directly to the `image` or `img/users` folder, or store all the images together and do away with the `img/users` folder.

Comment: Thank you! Subdomain use for static files (images) serving is best solution for me.